# Can't run the project cause of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, ios13, xcode11

I am working on a project and I have no professional experience on iOS development. Any way after I update my Xcode 11.0 (now it's 11.1) I can't run the project in any way. But if I try to open my 1 year old project it's open without any problem. I got all the time `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee4ac0e98)` and interesting part is error itself does not show up same spot. If I delete or modify the faulty field it just pop up completely different line. I want to show code but it does not occur in a specific place.

But error generally pops up the one of my third party code. I used [MyThirdPartyTextFieldAnimationFiles](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects/tree/master/TextFieldEffects/TextFieldEffects) and here I used `IsaoTextField.swift` and `TextFieldEffects.swift`. In `TextFieldEffect.swift` file declaration `public let placeholderLabel = UILabel()` gives the error first. I don't understand where the error originated from. Thanks for helping any way.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem but this solution won't be the right one. Error itself is so generic error type every can cause this. I explain my solution if one of you get that error he/she can use that maybe anyway.

In my app I have a NavigationController and one of my view(it is one of the views in the that NavVC) I declare the next VC at the start of the class and than push it to the top of the NavigationController. The error is cause by that declaration position. I moved it in the button function and error disappear.

Less buggy and nice days all.